# Dataframes columns get lost after using pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, concatenation

I have the following situation:
I have a dataframe with a column 'revisions' which is formated as a dictionary containing multiple other dictionaries with the keys 'a' and 'b'.
The revisions belong to the key column id. What I was trying to do is get rid of the dict format. Thus I wanted to list for every subdictionary its values along with the other columns of the dataframe. The new columns should then adopt the name of the keys ('a' and 'b')

Initial Dataframe:

```
id   column2 (dict_column)                             column3
0    {{'a': 91125, 'b': 233}{'a': 955, 'b': 267}}      Marc
1    {{'a': 91875, 'b': 455}{'a': 115, 'b': 267}}      Robert 
2    {{'a': 91955, 'b': 354}{'a': 255, 'b': 267}}      George
3    {{'a': 91565, 'b': 987}}                          Peter
4    {{'a': 95925, 'b': 896}}                          Hans
```

My objective:

```
id   a      b        column3
0    91125  233      Marc
0    955    267      Marc
1    91875  455      Robert 
1    115    267      Robert 
2    91955  354      George
2    255    267      George
3    91565  987      Peter
4    95925  896      Hans
```

Now, I searched for a way to do that and found a nice [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322552/convert-a-column-containing-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-multiple-columns-in-pandas) by using pd.concat.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['column2']],keys=df['id']).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Now my **Problem** is that the **'column 3'** get lost and it returns the following dataframe:

```
id   a      b  
0    91125  233      
0    955    267      
1    91875  455      
1    115    267      
2    91955  354      
2    255    267      
3    91565  987      
4    95925  896           ´
```

Do you guys have an idea what I do wrong?

Many thanks advance,

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

You are expanding the Series column2 into a data frame and then reassigning that data frame to df. Everything going on inside of pd.concat does not include column3. So when you reassign this result to df, you lose column3. The best way I know how to solve this is to assign the expansion of column2 into a new variable and then merge is back to df.

```
s = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['column2']],keys=df['id']).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
new_df = s.merge(df[['id','column3']],on='id')
```