# pandas rows of dictionary to columns

Tags: json, pandas, dictionary

I have a JSON file and while trying to read it into pandas its output is a row of dictionaries. What I want is these rows of dictionaries split where the keys are the column names.

Here is the first  line of the JSON file sample data

```
"{ \"time_iso8601\": \"2018-05-11T03:33:26+00:00\", \"request\": \"GET /atom/ HTTP/1.1\", \"request_uri\": \"/atom/\", \"scheme\": \"https\", \"host\": \"grochmal.org\", \"server_protocol\": \"HTTP/1.1\", \"status\": 301, \"request_method\": \"GET\", \"request_length\": 272, \"request_time\": 0.000, \"request_id\": \"43db8100f133bd2b011dbf649e304a0d\", \"remote_addr\": \"207.46.13.183\", \"remote_port\": 1217, \"cookie_userid\": \"\", \"cookie_sessionid\": \"\", \"cookie_csrftoken\": \"\", \"content_length\": \"\", \"content_type\": \"\", \"ssl_cipher\": \"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256\", \"ssl_curves\": \"0x001d:prime256v1:secp384r1\", \"ssl_protocol\": \"TLSv1.2\", \"ssl_session_reused\": \".\", \"http2\": \"\", \"http_user_agent\": \"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)\", \"http_x_forwarded_for\": \"\", \"http_referer\": \"\", \"http_x_csrf_token\": \"\", \"geoip_country_name\": \"United States\", \"geoip_country_code3\": \"USA\", \"geoip_city\": \"\", \"geoip_region_name\": \"\", \"geoip_latitude\": \"13.7500\", \"geoip_longitude\": \"100.4667\", \"gzip_ratio\": \"\", \"upstream_cache_status\": \"\", \"upstream_status\": \"\", \"upstream_response_time\": \"\", \"bytes_sent\": 486 }\n",
```

Here is my attempt

```
df_accesslog=pd.read_json(‘data.json')
train = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df_accesslog[0]).\
reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

the above is a direct use of

[Convert a column containing a list of dictionaries to multiple columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322552/convert-a-column-containing-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-multiple-columns-in-pandas#45322663)

[Here is the screenshot of the sample output of the above lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdsSm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` for convert `string`s to `list`s and then [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
import json, ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    

with open('data.json', encoding="utf8") as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

train = json_normalize([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in data])
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!